# Is it possible to direclty read a variable from a service worker (ServiceWorkerGlobalScope)?

Tags: javascript, security, variables, service-worker

Is it possible to get the `counter` variable (ServiceWorkerGlobalScope) from the main thread **without** using the postMessage method?

service-worker.js:

```
    let counter = 42;

    self.addEventListener("message", function (event: any) {
        let client = event.source;
        client.postMessage(counter);
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "main thread"? The worker's main thread surely can just read the variable, `let counter = 42; console.log(counter);`, the code doesn't need to be in a `message` event handler.

Comment: @Bergi I mean the thread that started the SW. Can it also somehow `console.log(counter)` ?

Comment: I'm still not sure, a service worker is started on its own when it needs to process some event. Do you mean the main thread of the page (browser tab) that originally registered the service worker? Then no, of course not.

Comment: @Bergi yes, I meant the main thread of the page (browser tab) that originally registered the service worker

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible to directly reference a variable from a different global scope.

You can use `postMessage()` to send values between the `WindowGlobalScope` and `ServiceWorkerGlobalScope`, as in your example.

You can also serialize variables to a shared storage that's accessible from both global scopes, like IndexedDB or the Cache Storage API. [`idb-keyval`](https://github.com/jakearchibald/idb-keyval) is an easy to use library that works in both scopes.

Comment: So even in case of XSS, a malicious script would not be able to access the variable directly but may receive it through calling the `postMessage()`? No other way?

Comment: @Senju In case of XSS, the malicious script can do everything to your server that your service worker can. A service worker is not a security barrier.

Comment: @Bergi Yes, I understand this. But the malicious script is unable to read a variable unless I `postMessage()` it?